# Responsive CSS Image size effects row sizes

Tags: html, css, responsive

I know this sounds like it's been asked before but I've played around with a lot of techniques I've found from other questions and nothing seems to get the desired effect I need.

I'm trying to make something that will be responsive like this:
[Responsive Example gif](https://i.stack.imgur.com/swOlf.gif)

I basically need an image to be centered, where the image is at 100% size.

---

Here is what I tried to get this effect:

I first made a div containing three child divs for "columns". Then inside the center column I made three child divs for "rows". Now I need the image to fill the max width it's allowed while still maintain that square aspect ratio. As well the height of the image should determine the height of the top and bottom rows.

Then it should just be a matter of having the text inside the top and bottom row align to the bottom and top of their divs respectively.

This would look something like this:

[HTML Visualization of columns](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RwZNz.png)

[HTML Visualization of center rows](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qQBqJ.png)

---

The issue I'm running into is I can't seem to get the center image to determine the heights of the rows above and below it.

I've tried...

- Flexbox
- using vh (view height)
- and a bit of using calc() but to no luck
- Setting aspect ration with `padding-top: 100%`

### What the code looks like

```css
/* .row & .col from materialize.css */

.full {
  height: 100vh;
}

.art_top {
  height: 10vh;
  /* I Don't actually want this fixed though */
  padding-bottom: 10px;
  display: flex;
}

.art_center {
  height: 80vh;
  /* I Don't actually want this fixed though */
}

.art_bottom {
  height: 10vh;
  /* I Don't actually want this fixed though */
  padding-top: 10px;
  display: flex;
}

#cover_art {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  background: center / cover no-repeat;
}

#song_name {
  align-self: flex-end;
}

#artist_name {
  align-self: flex-start;
}
```

```html
<div class="row">
  <div class="col s2 m3 full"></div>
  <div class="col s8 m6 full">
    <div class="row art_top">
      <a id="song_name" class="bold-title"></a>
    </div>
    <div class="row art_center">
      <div id="cover_art"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="row art_bottom">
      <a id="artist_name" class="bold-title"></a>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="col s2 m3 full"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please post your CSS as well. Please read: [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: @disinfor okay will do, I figured since I did it differently so many times I didn't know which would be the best to use. I'll add what I have in a moment

Comment: That's always the best way to go - just post what you currently have. You're less likely to have your question down voted - even if the approach you currently are using isn't the best, it still gives us a starting point.

Comment: @disinfor thanks for the tip! Good to know :)

Answer (score 0):

Flexbox makes this kind of layout very straightforward. The trick is selectively allowing items to flex or shrink.

The `flex` property shorthand takes 3 values for `flex-grow`, `flex-shrink`, and `flex-basis` (the initial width or height depending on flex direction). Just keep clear which divs are serving as flex containers as you get into the details in the layout. It is very common to have divs that are both flex containers and flex items themselves too.

I also recommend using an `img` element instead of applying the image as a background so you dont have trouble with the aspect ratio in responsive window sizes.

A very nice resource: https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/

```css
/* .row & .col from materialize.css */
body {
  margin: 0;
}
.full {
  height: 100vh;
}
.row {
  display: flex;
}
.column {
  flex: 1 1 auto;
}
.column2 {
  background: #b4c2cf;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}
.column1 {
  background: #cbb3cc;
}

.column3 {
  background: #cbb2b2;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
}
.art_top {
  flex: 1 0 10vh;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: flex-start
  align-self: flex-end;
}
.art_center {
  flex: 1 1 auto;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
}
.art_bottom {
  flex: 1 0 10vh;
  text-align: right;
}
#cover_art {
  max-width: 100%;
  max-height: 100%;
  width: auto;
  height: auto;
}
#song_name {
  align-self: flex-end;
}
#artist_name {
  align-self: flex-start;
}
.bold-title {
  display: block;
  font-weight: bold;
  padding: 10px;
}
.small-box {
  background: #8f588c;
  height: 100%;
  max-height: 70px;
  width: 100%;
  max-width: 70px;
}
```

```html
<div class="row full">
  <div class="column column1"></div>
  <div class="column column2">
    <div class="art_top">
      <a id="song_name" class="bold-title">My Album Title</a>
    </div>
    <div class="art_center">
      <img id="cover_art" src="https://picsum.photos/400" />
    </div>
    <div class="art_bottom">
      <a id="artist_name" class="bold-title">Artist Name</a>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="column column3">
    <div class="small-box"></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: This looks great! The only thing I'm noticing is that if you make the entire page width large and the height small you'll see the image looses it's aspect ratio and shrinks vertically. Also, so does this mean the size of the image has to be set? Like the `200px` you set? My thought here was that if I just had it fill no matter what pre-determined size, that way it could always use the max resolution image.

Comment: That’s the point at which you throw a media query in there and tweak the layout as needed. Most layouts have their limits at the extremes of viewport ratios.